# Will my AI algorithm for a python checkers game work and if not, what others should I consider?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I'll open with saying I'm not a data scientist or statistician so I've been trying to figure out the best way to score a set of given AI moves to help the computer determine which move path to choose. I've come up with the following and am asking if there is a better way to do this or if this will even work in the first place.

*For any given player:*

- Normal move +0
- Capture normal piece +1
- Capture king +2
- Move resulting in king +2
- Win game +10 (Should make AI highly prefer this path unless another provides a stronger and safer short term advantage.)
- Draw Game (Disregard path unless it's the only remaining option. Static 1 Goodness Point.)
- Lose Game (Disregard path unless it's the only remaining option. Static 0 Goodness Points.)

*I'm also toying with the following:*

- Move that ends against a wall +0.5
- Move that gains center control without threat +0.75
- Move that results in potential capture of multiple AI pieces (per piece) -0.25
- Move that results in piece getting "stuck" (within 1 turn) -0.5

The AI then runs through X levels *(Let's say 4)* of moves deep in the search tree and tallies points for both the player and opponent for each branch.

**I track the following (per branch):**

- Total points for AI
- Total points for human opponent
- Opponent likelihood of choosing branch *(see below)*
- Branch "Goodness" *(see below)*
- Total branches (move combinations)

In order to choose the best one, here is the algorithm I have developed but haven't determined if it will work well yet:

**Base Opponent Move Probability = 100 / Total Branches * (Human Opponent Points Gained + 1)**
**Player Branch "Goodness" = Human Opponent Probability * Total Points for AI Player**

**The AI then chooses the move branch with the highest "Goodness" points or picks one at random in event of a tie.**

Example:
4 Branches Available. In one of them, the human will king once and the AI will capture 2 pieces and king once.

**100 / 4 Moves * (1 Opponent Points + 1) = 50 Human Opponent Likelihood Score**

**50 Human Opponent Likelihood * 5 AI Player Points Gained = 250 Move "Goodness" Points**

*The only other thing I can think to add would be to score the entire board's "favorability" at the end of each branch and multiply that by the "Goodness" Score. Favorability meaning the total point score for all pieces, kings, center/wall control as a given end state. Though the more I expand on this the more it seems like I should pick one or the other. Either score as each of the moves in a branch are calculated **or** score the end board favorability result of each branch, not both.*

*Maybe something like: (Board Favorability / 2) * Goodness = Final Branch Value*

**Regardless, am I on the right track here? Will this approach work (not the favorability part, the general scoring and "Goodness" score for a given branch) or am I on the complete wrong track? Thanks for any assistance!**

Comment: It looks like you're trying to make an algorithm for Chess? If so, I would checkout the documentation and literature on AlphaZero and StockFish, as they're incredible Chess engines. Here's a YouTube video that sort-of summarizes [AlphaZero](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ciR6rA85tg). Just note that while AlphaZero may be better, I recall it being very fundamentally different than StockFish. I believe it has something to do with the time to think and approach to breadth vs. depth of search over that time. That said, I think your algorithm look good. Maybe consider an ElO modifier, though?

Comment: @zerecees - It's for checkers actually but either way should be the same principle.

Comment: @DavidCahill Just checking - are you aware how minimax search works? That's a good place to start if you've never thought about this before - AlphaZero is a bit down the road from that.

Comment: @NathanS. I am somewhat familiar with minmax but I need to research it more. Do you think the approach I have come up with might work or should I scrap it and look into something else? Even with minimax I'd need to establish what a given point value or win is right?

Comment: @DavidCahill I can answer your question now. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: See the [chessprogramming wiki](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Main_Page) for more advanced details. Though, you probably don't really need it here since it's just checkers.

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be helpful to think about the broader game-theoretic aspect of playing a game - this begins with the minimax algorithm, which I'll describe briefly.

Generally, the player playing next is considered to be a "max" player, and the other player is a "min" player. When you have a two-player perfect information (nothing hidden) zero-sum game (in this case all final outcomes are win/loss/draw), there is a fairly simple model of how to play - by building the full tree of the game.

So, the max player *considers* all their moves, and chooses the move which returns the max value. But, *considering* here is actually asking the min player to do the same, except the min player takes the min value (and then asks the max player to do this recursively and so on). If you continue this to the end of the game, in Checkers you get all wins, losses and draws, which might be assigned 100, -100, and 0. (The exact values don't matter, only the ordering of values.) Given enough time, you can iterate over the full tree and play perfectly.

In practice we don't have enough time, so we have to build an evaluation function that can cut off the tree at some depth and evaluate that, trying to predict the final outcome of the game. The lookahead gives us lots of information about what might happen, and so even with a simple evaluation function it can still lead to reasonable play. So, this is more or less what you are proposing - an evaluation function. If you put this on the end of a minimax search and correlate the values with the final win/loss/draw values, then you'll have a player that plays decent Checkers.

This is only the tip of the iceberg, but, yes, you are on the right track. When you get this working, here are some things you can look into:

- Alpha-beta pruning preserves the result but makes the tree much smaller.
- Real games are more like graphs that trees. Transposition tables detect transpositions into duplicate states and avoid re-searching the same tree twice.
- Iterative deepening helps you iterate through the tree to tune how deep you search.
- Endgame databases start solving the game from the end up, saving lots of computation and vastly increasing the strength of a program.
- Machine learning can be used to tune the values you are tuning by hand, or can be used for the whole process (ala AlphaZero)
- Monte-Carlo tree search samples possible lines of playout in a tree, which can help costly work tuning an evaluation function.

Finally, I'd recommend checking out the book [One Jump Ahead](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387765754) by Jonathan Schaeffer, which tells a fascinating story of how he built a world-champion checkers program and then eventually solved the game.

Edit: Note that a good software engineering approach would be to get the minimax search working with a very simple evaluation function (eg count material difference and king difference). When that is working, you can then look for weaknesses in play. A richer evaluation function will help fix those weaknesses. You can then iterate on this process.

If you spend too much time engineering features before you have the rest of the program working you may find that the features you thought you wanted are too expensive to compute/program in practice.

Comment: Thank you for the list of resouces here. I will definitely look into these for this and future projects!

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, and another answer already has lots of details, but one thing I want to highlight is that you should focus on evaluating *positions* rather than evaluating *moves*. The value of a move is simply the value of the position it ends up in.

- Instead of awarding lots of points to a "winning move", you award lots of points to a *won position*.
- Instead of awarding some points for a capture, and some more points for a king capture, you can score positions according to *material*. The reason we consider a capture a good move is because it deprives the opponent of pieces. Acquiring a king improves our own material. Evaluating positions on material takes these things into consideration.
- Likewise your rules about control of the center, being against the wall, etc. are much easier to do (and work better) as evaluations of a position, rather than tallying up points for "moves that result in X".

Win/lose/draw are "hard" conditions; if the game is over, it doesn't matter how much material you have left, or where it's placed, or anything else. You wouldn't choose a draw over a win just because the win sacrifices a piece. Evaluation rules for material, mobility, etc. are "rules of thumb" for how close a player is to winning, or how much ability they have to win, so you only really care about them when you *don't* have a forced win/loss/draw within your search horizon, and when you do use them, you want them to produce scores that are as similar as possible to the scores you would get if you *could* search every position until the end of the game.

You can start out assigning scores to your different evaluation rules by intuition, but to make them really good, you would simulate lots of games to the finish, and then run statistics on the winning and losing players' positions — then you would assign higher scores to the rules that most strongly correlate with positions that actually win.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you. I kept asking myself if I should evaluate board favorability (positions) and you've convinced me. I think it'll be easier from a coding perspective too.